# Magento bundle product SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, magento, bundle

When I modify  on Magento 1.7.0.2 simple products that belongs to a bundle, sometimes I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away.
```

In the mysql.slowquery.log appears this terrorific query:

```
Query_time: 30.408723  Lock_time: 0.000463 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 128
SET timestamp=1353399962;

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, 0 AS `tax_class_id`, 0 AS `price_type`, IF(IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_from_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_from_date.value, tad_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) IS NULL, 1, IF(IF(IFNULL(tas_special_to_date.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_special_to_date.value, tad_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.website_date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < 100 , ta_special_price.value, 0) AS `special_price`, tp.min_price AS `tier_percent`, IF(ta_price.value IS NULL, 0, ta_price.value) AS `orig_price`, 0 AS `price`, 0 AS `min_price`, 0 AS `max_price`, IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, 0, NULL) AS `tier_price`, IF(tp.min_price IS NOT NULL, 0, NULL) AS `base_tier`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0), NULL) AS `group_price`, IF(IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0) > 0, IF(gp.price IS NOT NULL AND gp.price > 0 AND gp.price < 100, gp.price, 0), NULL) AS `base_group_price`, gp.price AS `group_price_percent` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 CROSS JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg`
 CROSS JOIN `core_website` AS `cw`
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_group_price` AS `gp` ON gp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND gp.website_id = cw.website_id AND gp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 89 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 89 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_tax_class_id` ON tad_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 115 AND tad_tax_class_id.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_tax_class_id` ON tas_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 115 AND tas_tax_class_id.store_id = cs.store_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `ta_price_type` ON ta_price_type.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price_type.attribute_id = 117 AND ta_price_type.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_price` ON ta_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price.attribute_id = 69 AND ta_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_special_price` ON ta_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_price.attribute_id = 70 AND ta_special_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_from_date` ON tad_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_from_date.attribute_id = 71 AND tad_special_from_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_from_date` ON tas_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_from_date.attribute_id = 71 AND tas_special_from_date.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tad_special_to_date` ON tad_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_special_to_date.attribute_id = 72 AND tad_special_to_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `tas_special_to_date` ON tas_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_special_to_date.attribute_id = 72 AND tas_special_to_date.store_id = cs.store_id WHERE (e.type_id='bundle') AND (IF(IFNULL(tas_status.value_id, -1) > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) AND (ta_price_type.value=0) AND (e.entity_id IN(2399, 2400, 2401, 2402)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price_type` = VALUES(`price_type`), `special_price` = VALUES(`special_price`), `tier_percent` = VALUES(`tier_percent`), `orig_price` = VALUES(`orig_price`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `base_tier` = VALUES(`base_tier`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `base_group_price` = VALUES(`base_group_price`), `group_price_percent` = VALUES(`group_price_percent`);
```

In the database the table **catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp** is empty.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have timeouts configured in your MySQL server? The query updates some index and this can take long. Query time is exactly 30 seconds so there might be some timeout be set to 30s.

Comment: 30s to save one  attribute's product change ?. It´s a long time, that change insn't related with prices and... finally the table is empty, so the insert never occurs, even when sometimes the save's procedure it takes only a few seconds.

Comment: It looks like it is doing some kind of full reindex. I still would check if there is somewhere a timeout hitting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
try adding this line to **my.cnf**:

```
optimizer_search_depth = 5
```

[MySQL Doc -  Controlling the Query Optimizer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/controlling-optimizer.html)